# Laravel 6, как реализовать во время редиректа Flash сообщение?

Tags: laravel

В 6 версии Laravel базовая авторизация подключается при помощи

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

После любого действия (Идентификация, регистрация, выход) происходит редирект.
Требуется, после этих действий добавить Flash сообщение.

Реализовал это, непосредственно в

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers
```

Но ведь так не правильно делать? я так понимаю, что при любом обновлении laravel, всё может затереться и уже не будет работать?

Тогда как правильно настроить вывод Flash сообщений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что данный вопрос связан непосредственно с пакетом `laravel/ui`.

Существуют три пустых метода, связанных с аутентификацией, которые находятся в трейтах. Вы можете переопределить их в контроллерах вашего приложения по своему усмотрению.

**Регистрация**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

// ... остальной код

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
  // ... остальной код

  /**
   * Пользователь был зарегистрирован.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  mixed  $user
   * @return mixed
   */
  protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
  {
    //
  }
}
```

**Вход/выход**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

// ... остальной код

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  // ... остальной код

  /**
   * Пользователь прошел аутентификацию.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  mixed  $user
   * @return mixed
   */
  protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
  {
    //
  }

  /**
   * Пользователь вышел из приложения.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @return mixed
   */
  protected function loggedOut(Request $request)
  {
    //
  }
}
```

Ваш код в этих методах может содержать логику в двух вариациях:

```
// Первый вариант: возвращаем редирект.
return redirect('dashboard')->with('status', 'Успешный вход!');

// Второй вариант: только устанавливаем сообщение, ничего не возвращая.
// Будут отработаны редиректы, заданные по умолчанию.
session()->flash('status', 'Успешный вход!');
```